# visual studio 2010 shows const int 0 during debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, variables, constants

I have a `const int infoLTotal`  defined as a global variable like following:

```
const int MAX_NUM_GINSU_PER_CYCLE = 32; 
const int nViewPerGinsu = 256;

const int infoLTotal = MAX_NUM_GINSU_PER_CYCLE*nViewPerGinsu;
```

If I move my mouse on the variable of `infoLTotal`, it shows perfectly fine with `8192`. However, when I start debugging mode, I saw it shows 0? For example in following line

```
if (intX + intY < infoLTotal)  // infoLTotal shows 0 here, on mouse
```

But when I give its value to another variable, say a, a is indeed `8192`, like following:

```
int a = infoLTotal; // a shows 8192 here, but infoLTotal still shows 0, on mouse
```

So it looks that vs2010 is not showing what the const int truly is during the debug mode? Or is it really `0` ? I am confused.

Comment: Maybe it optimized away the variable so it shows 0 in debugging mode as there is no variable.

Comment: PDB loaded as expected? You can check the debug output to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test with your code in VS 2010 10.0.30319.1 shows 8192 when mouse hovers.

To debug your problem, you may firstly create a simple solution with only main function in it. Then copy and paste your code and test whether your IDE has bugs. If the test above passes, you have to comment out some of your codes until it shows 8192. And finally, re-exam the comment-out codes and find the problem.

My guess is VS bugs on a certain build.

PS: You said you are using debug mode. You still have to check if you build the project under Debug Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compiled your code in Debug, in order to prevent compiler from doing any optimization. Make a clean rebuild (remove all intermediate and target files by hand if necessary, including ipch and pdb files) and remove the sdf file at root of your solution. VS 2010 debugger sometimes messes up.